# SharePoint permission on Macs

Tags: macos, sharepoint

we are using SharePoint Server (MOSS 2007) with Windows Integrated Security.

A few computers in the company (managers) are using Apple Macs.

These people can't run the application on their machines!  I think the problem is due the windows integrated security.  How can we solve this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Sharepoint 2007 for our intranet portal using Windows integrated authentication with no (or few) problems for Macintosh users.  I just logged on to ours from my MacBook and was able to access it with no problems.  Can you describe what the problems are in more detail?  Not able to log on (should they be specifying a domain -- we have to)?  Controls broken? Are they standard or custom controls?  If custom controls, maybe the javascript isn't compatible with Safari.  Speaking of that does it matter which browser they use?  i.e., do you see the same problems in Safari and Firefox?

**EDIT**:  Just found this tidbit on our intranet site that may be helpful to avoid all the password prompts, though it requires Firefox.  I'll poke around some more to see if I can find a solution for Safari:

```
Using Firefox on a non-Windows workstation (e.g. Linux):
In Firefox, type about:config in the URL address bar and press Enter
Find network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris and double-click it
In the dialog box that comes up enter:
your-domain.goes.here.com
Click OK (Firefox should now use your Domain credentials to access these sites)
```

Comment: does it has to be kerbose authentication or NTLM also will work ??!!

Comment: Could be both.  Look here http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/523ae943-5e6a-4200-9103-9808baa00157.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 0):

On windows I had trouble using firefox on sharepoint. This should work on a mac as well.

There is a setting in **about:config network.ntlm.send-lm-response** set to false by default. Toggle it to true and you should be able to log on manually. Before making this change I would be prompted for a password on every page. Note: you need to login with **domain\username** as username.

The interface is a bit different in firefox without the activex but most functionality is still there. Sharepoint is highly integrated with internet explorer and the office suite. Without those two products sharepoint loses most of it's benefits.

On a side note: I'm actually surprised Microsoft hasn't made a bigger push for sharepoint. Sharepoint makes it very hard for an organization to migrate away from windows and office. If I was Microsoft I would be giving away sharepoint for next to free; the benefits to Microsoft would be vendor lock-in.

Comment: they do give it away for free, Windows SharePoint Services is a standard part of Windows 2003

Comment: Are you sure that network.ntlm.send-lm-response is the correct setting?  Setting this to true tells Firefox that it can send LAN Manager hashes of passwords (which are VERY weak) in response to a negotiate authentication request.  Does SharePoint really force IIS to use that insecure auth method?

Answer (score 0):

you could always switch to forms-based auth.

Answer (score -1):

*If I was Microsoft I would be giving away sharepoint for next to free*

They pretty much already are. They'll let you ditch all the first year's worth of licensing for everything needed. Which is smart, you become entrenched and it's that much more difficult for you to ever migrate away from Sharepoint.